# Servicestck.Ormlite equivalent of .include

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

Given the following example POCOS:

```
public class Order
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    ...

    [Reference]
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    ....
}
```

Is there a way to select a set of Orders and include their related items?  Akin to a .include() in Entity Framework.

In terms of Service Stack API, a multi-entity version of LoadSingleById() which does eagerly load referenced fields.